# Faye + Rails + Sending message in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sockets, faye

My `application_controller.rb`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def broadcast(channel, &block)
    message = {:channel => channel, :data => capture(&block)}
    uri = URI.parse("http://localhost:9292/faye")
    Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, :message => message.to_json)   
  end
end
```

In `posts_controller.rb`, I would like to do:

```
def create
  broadcast("/posts/new") do
    $('.user-win .posts').prepend('j(render('/posts/broadcast'))'));"
  end
end
```

But obviously it gives an error:

```
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (0 for 1))
 app/controllers/application_controller.rb:21:in `broadcast'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can not write JavaScript inside a controller action all you can do is to render a JavaScript template after the post has been successfully created and then inside your `create.js.erb` file call the broadcast method.

```
#posts_controller.rb

def create
  @post = Post.new(post_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @post.save
       format.js {render :status => :ok}
    else
       format.js {render :status => :unprocessable_entity}
    end
  end
end
```

Now make a 'create.js.erb' file inside `app/controllers/posts/` with the following code

```
#create.js.erb
<% if @post.errors.any? %>
   # render error
<% else %>
   # broadcast the newly created post to "/posts/new" channel
   <% broadcast("/posts/new") do %>
     $('.user-win .posts').prepend('<%=j render @post %>');     
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Now create a `_post.html.erb` file inside 'app/controllers/posts/' and write the html that you want to broadcast and render inside view